# Applying for UK Student Visa while on French Long Stay Visa

Tags: france, student-visa, uk-visa

I'm an Indian citizen and I'll be attending the first semester of my Master's in France from Sept '16 - Jan '17. As I'm part of a mobility programme, I'll be moving to UK for my second and third semesters (Jan - Jan '18). Technically, I'll have to apply for my UK Student visa from France.

I was told that to apply from another place other than my home country, I'll have to be "normally resident" (=> visa for more than six months). However, my period of study is only 5 months at the maximum. How can I go around this, since I do not have any break between semesters to be able to go back and apply?

I was under the impression that having a Long Stay visa in itself was a temporary residence permit and that it would suffice.

PS. I'm on an Erasmus Mundus scholarship if that helps in any way.

Comment: Do / will you have a titre de sejour in France? I think that should be enough but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, I'll be having a temporary Carte de Sejour at the most.